# Powershell: get-childitem doesn't work for filters

Tags: powershell, filter, get-childitem

I've got 3 ps1 files under d:

```
-a---         6/19/2015   2:52 PM        104 Untitled1.ps1                                                                                                                       
-a---         6/19/2015   2:56 PM        204 Untitled2.ps1                                                                                                                       
-a---         6/16/2015   1:17 PM       3073 Untitled3.ps1
```

I can use get-childitem to retrive them:

```
get-childitem d:\
```

But this fails:

```
 get-childitem d:\ -Force -Include *.ps1
```

This command doesn't show any thing. Why? I just want to filter out .ps1 file. Anything wrong with my command?

Answer (score 5):

> The Include parameter is effective **only when the command includes the
>   Recurse** parameter **or the path leads to the contents of a directory**,
>   such as C:\Windows*, where the **wildcard character** specifies the
>   contents of the C:\Windows directory.

Source: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849800.aspx

You can use the -Filter parameter instead:

```powershell
Get-ChildItem -Path 'd:\' -Filter '*.ps1'
```

Or if you need to filter multiple extensions, use the wildcard character:

```powershell
Get-ChildItem -Path 'd:\*' -Include '*.ps1', '*.bat'
```

Comment: What if I wish to filter 2 types of file, "ps1", and "bat". How to write this command?